# Using specific try catch, error overrides

Tags: java

This is my Exception:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

private String errorCode="Unknown_Exception";

public MyException(String message, String errorCode){
    super(message);
    this.errorCode=errorCode;
}

public String getErrorCode(){
    return this.errorCode;
}
}
```

Now immagine the next scenario, the code is way too long to paste here:
1 I got a Presentation class made in Swing in Presentation package
2 In package calculations I made simple operations with few numbers from received database fields
3 In package connections I got the database connections

Trouble comes here:
-In presentation layer I catch all errors, like this:

```
    try {
        //here is a method called updateCombo() wich throws: 
        //throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"ERROR_UPDATING_COMBO_BOX");
    } catch (MyException ex) {
        try {
            //Here we process error code, if error is not defined, uses default errors.
            processCode(ex);
        } catch (MyException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(Presentacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    }
```

processCode is a simple list with cases, like this:

```
private void processCode(MyException e) throws MyException {
    switch (e.getErrorCode()) {
        case "ERROR_UPDATING_COMBO_BOX":
            lblErrorText.setText("Error updating combo.");
            throw e;
        case "ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY":
            lblErrorText.setText("Error selecting PK");
            throw e;
        case "ERROR_OPENING_CONNECTION":
            lblErrorText.setText("Error opening connection.");
            throw e;
        default:
            lblErrorText.setText("Excepcion not defined: "+ e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the scenario, the connection fails in 3rd package and leads to this:

```
throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"ERROR_OPENING_CONNECTION");
```

As I said, the error is thrown to the upper layer with throws clause in method header, this beeing 2nd package.
2nd package also throws a new exception to Presentation, because of failing connection:

```
throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY");
```

Presentation methods also throw this exception becase 2nd layer failed:

```
throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"ERROR_UPDATING_COMBO_BOX");
```

### The main problem:

Using debug i found out that the program does what it has to do. It gets to the connection layer and does this successfully:

```
throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"ERROR_OPENING_CONNECTION");
```

But, in 2nd layer, calculations, if connection fails it throws a new exception:

```
throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY");
```

This is the problem:

```
throw new
```

throwing new exception overrides ERROR_OPENING_CONNECTION with ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY. When it gets to presentation due to its "throw new" overrides ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY with ERROR_UPDATING_COMBO_BOX, resulting in the final error shown in the screen:

```
lblErrorText.setText("Error updating combo.");
```

Is there any way to return to presentation once first error is caught without overriding by next errors?
Maybe I misunderstood the concept but I want to catch all possible errors because:
-If connection is OK but method in 2nd layer fails it should throw ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY. 
-If 2nd layer (calculations) does it OK but there is error in presentation it should lead to ERROR_UPDATING_COMBO_BOX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `e.getCause()` which will return a `Throwable` and check if this cause belongs to `MyException`. In case it is, you can check the `e.getCause()` again recursively until you obtain the deepest error code in the stacktrace and perform the validation for this exception.

Here's an example:

```
public MyException getDeepestException(MyException e) {
    Throwable t = e.getCause();
    if (t instanceof MyException) {
        return getDeepestException((MyException)t);
    }
    return e;
}
```

As pointed out by [@RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic), in order to use this approach, you will need to add an additional constructor to your custom exception:

```
public MyException(String message, Throwable cause, String errorCode){
    super(message, cause);
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}
```

And when throwing your exception, call the proper constructor:

```
try {
    //...
} catch (SomeException e) {
    throw new MyException(<a proper message should be here>, e, "ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY");
}
```

Comment: ok, this goes into MyException class but how do i use it in presentation?

Comment: This would be the exact exception you want to use in `processCode` method.

Comment: Note that for this to be useful, the constructor of MyException has to be changed to accept a cause, and has to call the appropriate `super()` to set that cause.

Comment: @RealSkeptic can you post it in your comment? :P

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ok done but not working yet, xD must i change anything in MyException class?

Comment: There is no option to post code snippets in a comment. If you meant my answer, well, it offers a different approach in which this is irrelevant.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you can do it by wrapping text with ` character: `System.out.println("this is an example");`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Not multiline code, which is what you want if you want to explain how to pass a parameter in a constructor and call a super constructor.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you can edit other people answer as well and complement the info in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, if the exception caught by one package happens to be a MyException, you want the original MyException to be passed up, otherwise (if the exception is some other type of Exception) you want to create a new MyException.

In this case, you should have two catch clauses.

```
try {
    // Whatever you do in the try clause
} catch ( MyException myEx ) {
    throw myEx;
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"ERROR_SELECTING_PRIMARY_KEY");
}
```